# What does this phrase "The chance of being wrecked" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> "This is a serious thing," said the doctor to me.' The island is still
>   in the grip of that wretched current flowing southward. We will have
>   to look into this tomorrow. If nothing can be done about it, the
>   Indians had better take to canoes and leave the island. **The chance of**
>   **being wrecked** will be better than getting frozen to death in the
>   ice-floes of the Antarctick."

This is from a novel "The Voyages Of Doctor Dolittle".
I couldn't understand the meaning of this phrase "The chance of being wrecked". What does this phrase mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, "chance" means the possibility of something happening:

> 3. a possibility or probability of anything happening ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/chance?s=t))

"Wrecked" means to be destroyed, and is often used in a naval context (with the canoes mentioned by the doctor.)

The definition of the verb "wreck":

> 7. to cause the wreck of (a vessel); shipwreck. ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/wrecked))

The phrase "the chance of being wrecked" means something like "the possibility of being destroyed [by that 'wretched current']."

Since the chance of being wrecked is not 100%, the doctor surmises that the risk of leaving in the canoes (**the chance of being wrecked**) is preferable (**better**) to freezing to death in the Antarctic.

He would rather take the chance of canoeing away than almost certainly die on the ice-floes.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. I got it. Now I know this "chance" means risk.

Comment: Sorry, did I define the wrong word for you? haha

Comment: No, I first think chance means favorable opportunity and why being wrecked is favorable opportunity but when chance means risk, I may be able to understand this phrase easier.

Comment: Well, either way, I'm glad you understand.